# How can I let me users download a file from my jDeveloper 10g website?

Tags: java, http, jdeveloper

I want to easily allow my users to fetch a PDF file located on my hard disk.

How could I "push" the file to them so the download/open file prompt opens for them?

Comment: JDeveloper..why on earth are you using this :)

Answer (score 0):

Run a web server on your computer.   This one - http://www.acme.com/java/software/Acme.Serve.Serve.html - is powerful enough to do what you want, and small enough to be easy to setup and run.

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the file to the website, and give them a link to it. It will open in Adobe Reader, or they can Right Click > Save As to save it to their computer.

By default, the browser only opens the Download/Save dialog when presented with a file type that it, and all it's plugins, are unable to handle.